# Stereoselectivity of 1,3-dipolar cycloadditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, pericyclic, stereoselectivity

How do the 1,3-dipolar cycloadditions follow the *endo* rule as in the reaction below, where the *anti* diastereoisomer is formed predominantly?

[image]